# How to send an xml file from a linux based machine to a server

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, network-shares

I would like to ask which is the best command for linux to send an xml file to a specific ip. netcat, ssh or ftp. And is it possible to send the file every 10 minutes?

Comment: You should consider rewording your question, you are likely going to be closed given that you are requesting "the best", which is subjective.  Instead, perhaps show things you tried and maybe ask for an objective comparison (or if you haven't tried anything, just ask how to do it on a schedule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without knowing what server is behind the ip in question. But in general, i'd scp the file using public-key authentication. So: setup your local ssh keys, upload the public key to the server's authorized_keys2 file, and then just

```
scp /path/to/file user@host:/path/to/target-dir
```

On Linux, you can automatize this using cron. So if you want to run the upload every ten minutes, add this to your crontab

```
*/10 * * * * scp /path/to/file user@host:/path/to/target-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line) is a nice SO post on this. And to send xml file you can use [cron jobs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) . Cron jobs can be used to run any jobs at scheduled intervals in linux.

Comment: Thanks very much. Really helpful. The only thing is that it is not a pc or laptop which has linux. It is a communication card which is unix based. Is it also possible to use cron jobs?